# Disable SelectedImageIndex in Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, image, treeview

I'm using a treeview-control in winforms and an imagelist to display different states of the treeview-elements.

But i don't want to use the selected element to use a different image.

Is there a way to disable SelectedImageIndex in the TreeView-control?

If tried to change the selectedimageindex after every selection. Something like this:

```
    private void TreeView1AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView1.SelectedImageIndex = treeView1.SelectedNode.ImageIndex;
    }
```

But this causes a pretty ugly flickering of the control after every selection..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you are **creating** the new `TreeNode`, assign the same imageindex to `ImageIndex` and `SelectedImageIndex`:

```
...
node.SelectedImageIndex = node.ImageIndex;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating the node

```
Dim nd As New TreeNode("NodeKey", "NodeText", 1, 1)
```

The two indices are for ImageIndex and SelectedImageIndex.